# Is there any alternative of InvokeShellVerb in NSIS Script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, nsis

I want to pin shortcut to taskbar in windows 10. Script works fine but my utily is detected as malware trojan. Microsoft has removed the verb and this could be the reason for the same. So is there any alternative way to pin/unpin any program programatically.

```
    OutFile "C:\PinUnpinExe\PinUnpinShortcut.exe"

!include 'StdUtils.nsh'
!include FileFunc.nsh

SilentInstall silent
RequestExecutionLevel user ;no elevation needed
ShowInstDetails hide

var inputParam
Section
    ${GetParameters} $inputParam
    System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentDirectory(i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t .r0)"
    ${StdUtils.InvokeShellVerb} $0 "$0" "abc.exe" $inputParam
SectionEnd
```

This line is detected as virus.

```
 ${StdUtils.InvokeShellVerb} $0 "$0" "abc.exe" $inputParam
```

I'm ok with the other language solutions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't programmatically pin shortcuts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141230-00/?p=43273/), the taskbar is [a place for **users**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673/) to put their favorite icons!

To unpin you can do this (NSIS 3+):

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Win\COM.nsh"

!macro UnpinShortcut lnkpath
Push $0
Push $1
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_StartMenuPin} ${IID_IStartMenuPinnedList} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    System::Call 'SHELL32::SHCreateItemFromParsingName(ws, p0, g "${IID_IShellItem}", *p0r1)' "${lnkpath}"
    ${If} $1 P<> 0
        ${IStartMenuPinnedList::RemoveFromList} $0 '(r1)'
        ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
    ${EndIf}
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
Pop $1
Pop $0
!macroend

Section Uninstall
!insertmacro UnpinShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk"
SectionEnd
```